# How to select which OS kernel to upgrade when multiple OS'es are installed?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, configuration, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my kernel on a machine with multiple OS'es. I have a Red Hawk OS (a real-time Red Hat variant) and Red Hat installed. I can select which OS to boot into using grub.

I'd like to upgrade the Red Hat OS which is currently running kernel 2.6 to kernel 3.11.

I booted into the Red Hat OS using Grub and then I followed the instructions here (which I have used successfully before to upgrade a CentOS):
http://www.linuxfunda.com/2013/11/08/how-to-upgrade-the-kernel-on-centos/

However the commands seem to upgrade my Red Hawk OS instance instead of the Red Hat OS instance.

When I look at the grub entries I see the following:

```
title RedHawk Linux (3.10.37)
   root (hd0,0)
   kernel /vmlinuz-3.10.37 ro root=/dev/mapper/vg_dornier-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD rd_LVM_LV=vg_dornier/lv_swap SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=auto rd_LVM_LV=vg_dornier/lv_root  KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM rhgb nmi_watchdog=0 enforcing=0 quiet isolcpus=6,7
   initrd /initramfs-3.10.37.img
```

How can I appropriately select which OS to upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `/boot/grub/grub.conf`, and then find proper stanza for your RHEL. Change vmlinuz-* and initramfs-* to proper files.

Comment: The problem is that the vmlinuz-* being built is using the wrong base. So when I try to boot with given vmlinuz it starts loading Red Hawk with the 3.10 kernel instead of Red Hat.